# Problemas al refrescar información en un selectpicker

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy usando un selectpicker para mostrar las empresas registradas y al selecionar una llena un segundo objeto selectpicker con los cargos relacionados a dicha empresa y así registra a el trabajador con la empresa y el cargo.

Al crear un nuevo registro funciona bien, pero al modificar asigno el valor de la empresa y cargo a los selectpicker, me muestra la opcion de la empresa pero el del cargo solo se muestra si coloco una alerta alert(usedatos[3]);

La alerta me indica el valor correcto del cargo es decir que la data esta bien el problema es que no refresca el form, ya intente refrescar los selectpicker. Pero nada.

¿Alguna idea?

Les dejo el fragmento donde asigno los valores que bienen de BD a los selectpicker,

```
var varid=""+$(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
$("#idregistro").val(varid);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
   url: "include/i_async.php",
   data:"accion=searchusuempbyid&useid="+varid,
   success: function(data){
      var usedatos=data.split("##");
      $("#empid").selectpicker('val', usedatos[2]);
      Load_Cargos(usedatos[2],varaccion);
      alert(usedatos[3]);
      $("#carid").selectpicker('val',usedatos[3]);
   }
});
```

Comment: aunque la parte de php no se ejecute, puedes añadir un ejemplo reproducible con html y javascript ?

Comment: Que hace Load_Cargos??

Comment: Hola Daniel, Load_cargos trae los la lista de cargos que estan relacionados a la empresa. esa lista la utilizo para llenar el select de cargos

Answer (score 0):

Listo, el problema era que se ejecutan 2 consultas a la BD y una se tardaba en devolver la informacion, coloque un await y listo.

Comment: Hola licorgana, me alegro de que encontraras la solución y la compartieses con la comunidad. Te comento que la publicación ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido, sería ideal que añadieses algo más de detalle. Por ejemplo, ¿cuál es el código necesario para el await? ¿Y dónde iría dentro de tu código?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta refrescando el select:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```